# Block developer Tools from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to Block the Developer Tools of Chrome through a Chrome Extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is only possible through a [domain policy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2657289?hl=en).

Comment: So they only work when they are done in a cloud-managed way and a per device?

Comment: Windows domain policy stuff will work as well for an organization. Not sure what the policy name for that is though.